# $fg\in L_{2}[a,b]$ for all $f\in L_{2}[a,b]$ implies $\lVert g \rVert_{\infty} < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to see the implication that if $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $fg \in L_{2}[a,b]$ for all $f \in L_{2}[a,b]$ then $\lVert g \rVert_{\infty} < \infty$.

My attempt for this is to consider the function $f \equiv 1\in L_{2}[a,b]$ and see that $fg = g \in L_{2}[a,b]$. Then, any $g^{n} \in L_{2}[a,b]$ for all $n$. But no other idea emerge to show that $\lVert g\rVert_{\infty} < \infty$. Any help would be appreciated.

Diego.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\phi f \in L^p(\mu)$ whenever $f\in L^p(\mu)$, then $\phi \in L^\infty(\mu)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902010/phi-f-in-lp-mu-whenever-f-in-lp-mu-then-phi-in-l-infty-mu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more straightforward way to prove without invoking anything in functional
analysis: Prove by contradiction. Suppose that contrary that $||g||_{\infty}=\infty$.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_{n}=\{x\in[a,b]\mid|g(x)|>n\}$. Note that $\lambda(A_{n})>0$
(otherwise, $n$ is an essential upper bound of $g$). It is clear
that $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$ and $\cap_{n}A_{n}=\{x\mid|g(x)|=\infty\}=\emptyset$.
By continuity of measure, $\lim_{n}\lambda(A_{n})=\lambda(\cap_{n}A_{n})=0$.
Define $B_{n}=A_{n}\setminus A_{n+1}=\{x\mid|g(x)|\in(n,n+1]\}$.
Note that $\lambda(B_{n})>0$ for infintely many $n$. (For, if there
exists $N$ such that $\lambda(B_{n})=0$ whenever $n\geq N$, then
$\lambda(A_{N})=\lambda(A_{N+1})=\lambda(A_{N+2})=\ldots$. It follows
that $\lim_{n}\lambda(A_{n})=\lambda(A_{N})>0$, which is a contradiction.).
Also note that $B_{1},B_{2},\ldots$ are pairwisely disjoint.

Choose a sequence of integers $(n_{k})$ such that $1\leq n_{1}<n_{2}\leq\ldots$
and $\lambda(B_{n_{k}})>0$ for each $k$. Define $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda(B_{n_k})}}1_{B_{n_{k}}}.$
Observe that $\int f^{2}d\lambda=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}<\infty$.
Therefore $f\in L^{2}[a,b]$. By assumption, $fg\in L^{2}$. However,
by direct calculation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|fg|^{2}d\lambda & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{B_{n_{k}}}\frac{1}{k^{2}\lambda(B_{n_{k}})}g^{2}(x)d\lambda(x)\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{B_{n_{k}}}\frac{1}{k^{2}\lambda(B_{n_{k}})}\cdot(n_{k})^{2}d\lambda(x)\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{B_{n_{k}}}\frac{d\lambda(x)}{\lambda(B_{n_{k}})}\\
 & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1\\
 & = & \infty,
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice answer.  If I may suggest, you can make your first paragraph more direct by defining the sets $B_n$ directly. For instance:

Comment: "... Prove by contradiction. Suppose that contrary that $||g||_{\infty}=\infty$.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $B_{n}=\{x\mid|g(x)|\in(n,n+1]\}$. Note that $\lambda(B_{n})>0$ for infintely many $n$. (For, if there
exists $N$ such that $\lambda(B_{n})=0$ whenever $n\geq N$, then, since $\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n = \{x \mid|g(x)| > N\}$, we have $\lambda(\{x \mid|g(x)| > N\})= \lambda(\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty B_n)\leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty\lambda(B_n)=0$. So 
$||g||_{\infty}\leq N$. Contradiction.)
Also note that $B_{1},B_{2},\ldots$ are pairwisely disjoint."

Answer (score 5):

By the assumption, the operator $M_g:f\mapsto fg$ is everywhere defined. It is also closed, so it is bounded by the closed graph theorem.

Then, letting
$\{ x\in [a,b]:|g(x)|\geq n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}=:\Omega_n$ we have
$$
n^2\mu(\Omega_n)\leq \int_a^b\mathbb{1}_{\Omega_n}(x)|g(x)|^2d\mu(x)\leq \|M_g\|^2\mu(\Omega_n)
$$
forcing $\mu(\Omega_n)=0$ for large enough $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (otherwise, we may divide through by $\mu(\Omega_n)$ and find a contradiction). Thus, $g\in L^\infty$.

edit: to see $M_g$ is closed, let $f_n\to f$ and $gf_n\to h$ in $L^2[a,b]$. Then, along a subsequence $n'$, $f_n'(x)\to f(x)$ for a.e. $x$. Thus, $g(x)f_n'(x)\to g(x)f(x)$ a.e., and $h=gf$.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you give a hint on how to see that $M_g$ is closed? This seems to be the main fact, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you. I added some details above.

Comment: Thanks! Really nice proof.