# How to prove that a linear operator F is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let \begin{equation}
p \in[1, \infty) \text { şi }\left(\alpha_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}
\end{equation} . Show that the linear operator \begin{equation}
F: l^p \rightarrow l^p
\end{equation} given by \begin{equation}
F\left(\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\right)=\left(\alpha_n x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
\end{equation} for all \begin{equation}
\left(x_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^p
\end{equation}  is continuous and it's norm is \begin{equation}
\|F\|=\left\|\left(\alpha_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\right\|_{\infty} .
\end{equation}

I try to find a real number l such that the norm of F times x is less or equal to l times norm of x but i don't know how to prove this.I don't know if i'm on a good path.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: A similar question in the more general setting of $L_p(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ spaces has been discussed here[$\phi f \in L^p(\mu)$ whenever $f\in L^p(\mu)$, then $\phi \in L^\infty(\mu)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902010/phi-f-in-lp-mu-whenever-f-in-lp-mu-then-phi-in-l-infty-mu)

Comment: If memory serves, the norm of $F$ is the supremum of the norm of $F(x)$ for $x$ of norm no greater than $1.$ This should get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Recall that a linear operator is continuous iff it is bounded and iff it is continuous at a single point.